# Fixed position sidebar within a flex container

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, position

I have a layout which uses flexbox to position a main content section and a sidebar element beside each other, with `justify-content: space-between` for consistent spacing within a container, however I need the sidebar on the right to also scroll down the page with the user by using `position: fixed`, whilst also remaining pinned to the right edge of the container.

Example pen: https://codepen.io/StyleMeLikeOneOfYourFrenchGirls/pen/BazQOLj

```css
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left-content {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: red;
}

.right-sidebar {
  height: 200px;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: yellow;
  /*position: fixed;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="content">
    <div class="left-content">
    left content
    </div>
    
    <div class="right-sidebar">
    right sidebar
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I understand that `fixed` removes the element from document flow, and thus eliminates the simplicity of the flex layout and the ability to 'contain' something within it's parent element.

I've been able to achieve something close to what I want, but it requires specific values for different viewport widths (e.g. using Bootstrap's `offset` classes, `transform: translateX()` or various combinations of margins). These methods are messy though, and don't provide a consistent solution to keeping the sidebar aligned with the edge of the parent container.

Is there a simpler/more elegant solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position: sticky;`. It respects the flex and has a fixed purpose.

### DEMO:

```css
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left-content {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: red;
}

.right-sidebar {
  height: 200px;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="content">
    <div class="left-content">
    left content
    </div>
    
    <div class="right-sidebar">
    right sidebar
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look...

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.content {
  background: #999;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
}
.leftContent {
  display: flex;
  width: calc( 100% - 300px );
}
.rightSidebar {
  position: absolute;
  right: calc(50% - 500px);
  background: #666;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="leftContent">
      a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a. a a a a. a a a a a a a a. a a a a a a a aa. a a       a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a. a a a a. a a a a a a a a. a a a a a a a aa. a aa<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>
      
    </div>
    <div class="rightSidebar">
      b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a try with minimum impact on your code.
The setup you have limits a bit the options you have, but I think below Pen would be a nice workaround.

```
.left-content {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 70%;
  background-color: red;
}

.right-sidebar {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 15%;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20%;
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/satira/pen/dyXOQWm)

Sidebar on the right hand side scrolls down the page with the user by using position: fixed, whilst also remaining pinned to the right edge of the container.